# How to use multi specifiers to format column in asciidoc

Tags: asciidoc

In AsciiDoc manual [23.2. Column Formatting](https://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#cols-format), it says:

> To apply a specifier to a column, you must set the cols attribute and assign it a value. A column specifier can contain any of the following components:
>
> - multiplier
> - align
> - width
> - style
>
> Each component is optional.

But I didn't find an example that uses multi specifiers.

For example, I want to use both width and style specifiers in the below table.

```
[cols="h,a,a",options="header"]
|=== 
|   | compare times     | move times
| 1 | n-1               | 2n-2
| 2 | (n-1)(n+4)/4      | (n-1)(n+8)/4
| 3 | (n-1)(n+2)/2      | (n-1)(n+4)/2
|===
```

Since the first column contains few text, so I want to add the attribute `[cols="1,4,4"]` to it.

I don't know how to implement that, could somebody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The section of the Asciidoctor documentation that you linked to does include multiple examples of composite column formatting specifiers, including relative widths, centering, left/right alignment, vertical alignment, and styles.

For your table, your `cols` specification should be:

```
[cols="1h,4a,4a", options="header"]
```